# Permission for Android app works even after it is swiped and stopped

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

What permission should I enable to make the app run 24/7 like antivirus. I have searched a lot but cannot find a specific answer.

Comment: What do you specifically need to do?

Comment: My app actually looks for particular WiFi ssid and if it is available it will automatically at any time.

Comment: As Adithya said, you should look into Services, Google has optimized almost any kind of behaviour so that you don't need to do any kind of "polling".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) which runs in background until stopped by user.